# SOQL Query for Related Custom Objects

Tags: soql, query, custom, object

I'm currently trying to write a SOQL Query to pull all Accounts that have < 5 related Contact objects AND No related `ts2__Placement__c` objects (custom object).

I have successfully been able to pull all Accounts that have < 5 related Contact objects using below:

```
Select AccountId, Count(Id)  from Contact group by AccountId having count(Id) > 5
```

However, I'm having trouble with how the custom object relates into that query. I assume it'll have to nest as a sub-query.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a WHERE Clause using a [`Left Inner Join`](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com#Left_Inner_Join) (actually I guess it would be a [`Left Anti Join`](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com#Left_Anti_Join)) here:

```
SELECT ...
FROM Contact
WHERE Id NOT IN (
    SELECT Contact__c FROM My_Object__c
)
GROUP BY ...
HAVING ...
```